# Access file from root folder inside node module

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I am using a custom module in my nodeJs application. I need to access a method from a file ( testData.js)that is located in  my application src folder inside the module.

I tried accessing the method inside the module as below

```
const {testMethod} = require('./src/testData');
```

But this is not detecting the file .

below is the folder structure

```
test-application
|
 node_modules
 |
  custom_module
  |
   customFile.js
 src
 | 
  testData.js
```

Please suggest on how to proceed with this

Comment: Is it due to the destructuring method? Or you simply try const testMethod.

Comment: I am using a custom module in my nodeJs application. I need to access a method from a file ( testData.js)that is located in my application src folder inside the module.

I tried accessing the method inside the module as below

const testMethod = require('./src/testData'); This is also giving same error

Comment: can't see your server.js. How about const testMethod = require('../src/testData') 2 dots? Because your directory/file path is not so clear. What is your error message anyway.

Comment: I tried with two dots, still getting error as method not found

Comment: Limited details, can't advise much. If you can share more codes and paths, it will be helpful.